# Bin repacking algorithm with limited 'temp' space

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, packing, bin-packing

Basic bin packing algorithms and implementations can be found all over the internet.  However, I am looking for an algorithm that will repack a bin using a limited amount of temporary space.  The idea is that items were added haphazardly to the bin and now need to be re-organized to minimize wasted space.  Can anyone point me to such an algorithm / implementation or how to get started?

EDIT (more details):

Legend for images:

- Light gray = empty space
- All other colors = rectangles to pack into
  the bin

As kcsquared mentioned, this is really a rectangle packing problem. For what I am trying to do, rotation of items is not allowed.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

Let's say we start with this container.  As you can see, there's a lot of wasted space that prevents more items from being added easily.

[image]

The end result would look something like this (no doubt this is not optimal, I just did this by hand...):

[image]

However, when moving items around, the idea is that they can't just come out of the bin and go 'no where'.  When an item is taken out, it has to go somewhere else.  For that purpose, we have a temporary space that items can be placed in to make room in the primary bin.  This temporary space is smaller but big enough to hold the largest item (and more than one item at a time).  It is also a rectangle.

[image]

Happy to add more details or answer any additional questions. Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Can you define that problem more rigorously?

Comment: Agreed with Harold- the current statement is critically lacking in details, and needs both examples and more information. It also seems to possibly be about rectangle packing, since the bin-packing problem has 1-dimensional capacities in bins, so 'repacking' a single bin doesn't make sense. It's also not clear how the 'repacking' problem is distinct from the normal packing problem.

Comment: More details added.  Please let me know if that helps or if I can answer any additional questions.